# Ao converter um objeto em JSON, porque ocorre o aparecimento de vários caracteres "\"

Tags: java, json

Para realizar a conversão Bean para JSON,  vice e versa, estou usando a biblioteca `org.json` para JAVA.
Porém apesar de um objeto ser convertidos normalmente , outros acabam por serem carregados de caracteres `\`, quando convertido para JSON ,e apesar de nenhuma exceção ser disparada, nenhuma chave é reconhecida.

CONVERTER VALOR

```
 public String getUserJSONObject(User bean)
 {
     JSONObject object = new JSONObject();
     JSONObject values = new JSONObject();
     try {
         values.put("password",bean.getPassword());
         values.put("email", bean.getEmail());
         values.put("id", bean.getId());
         values.put("username", bean.getUsername());
         values.put("image", bean.getImage());
         values.put("name", bean.getName());
         object.put("user",values);
     }catch(Exception ex){}
     return object.toString();
 }

 public String getQuestionItemJSONObject(QuestionItem bean)
 {
     JSONObject object = new JSONObject();
     JSONObject values = new JSONObject();
     try{
         values.put("id",bean.getId());
         values.put("value",bean.getValue());
         object.put("questionItem",values.toString());
     }catch(Exception ex){}
     return object.toString();
 }
```

RESULTADO

```
{"user":{"id":1,"username":"username","email":"email","name":"name","image":"image","password":"password"}}
{"questionItem":"{\\"id\\":1,\\"value\\":\\"item1\\"}"}
```

RECUPERAR VALOR

```
  public User getUser(String jsonString)
 {
     try{
         return getUser(new JSONObject(jsonString));
     }catch(Exception ex){return null;}
 }
 public User getUser(JSONObject object)
 {
     User bean = new User();
     try{
         JSONObject values = object;
         if (object.has("user"))values = object.getJSONObject("user");
         if (values.has("id")) bean.setId(values.getInt("id"));
         if (values.has("name")) bean.setName(values.getString("name"));
         if (values.has("username")) bean.setUsername(values.getString("username"));
         if (values.has("password"))bean.setPassword(values.getString("password"));
         if (values.has("email"))bean.setEmail(values.getString("email"));
         if (values.has("image"))bean.setImage(values.getString("image"));
     }catch(Exception ex){}
     return bean;
 }
public QuestionItem  getQuestionItem(String jsonString)
 {
     try{
         return getQuestionItem(new JSONObject(jsonString));
     }catch(Exception ex){return null;}
 }
 public QuestionItem  getQuestionItem(JSONObject object)
 {
     QuestionItem bean = new QuestionItem();
     try{
         JSONObject values = object;
         if(object.has("questionItem")) values = object.getJSONObject("questionItem");
         if(values.has("id"))bean.setId(values.getInt("id"));
         if(values.has("value"))bean.setValue(values.getString("value"));
     }catch(Exception ex){}
     return bean;
 }
```

RESULTADO

A primeira bean não apresentou problema , a segunda não reconheceu nenhuma chave,
algumas beans chegam a apresentar inúmeras barras, por exemplo:

```
{"question":"{\\"id\\":1,\\"correct\\":\\"{\\\\\\"questionItem\\\\\\":\\\\\\"{\\\\\\\\\\\\\\"id\\\\\\\\\\\\\\":4,\\\\\\\\\\\\\\"value\\\\\\\\\\\\\\":\\\\\\\\\\\\\\"item4\\\\\\\\\\\\\\"}\\\\\\"}\\",\\"items\\":\\"{\\\\\\"questionItemList\\\\\\":\\\\\\"[\\\\\\\\\\\\\\"{\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\"questionItem\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\":\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\"{\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\"id\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\":1,\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\"value\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\":\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\"item1\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\"}\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\"}\\\\\\\\\\\\\\",\\\\\\\\\\\\\\"{\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\"questionItem\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\":\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\"{\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\"id\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\":2,\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\"value\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\":\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\"item2\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\"}\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\"}\\\\\\\\\\\\\\",\\\\\\\\\\\\\\"{\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\"questionItem\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\":\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\"{\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\"id\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\":3,\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\"value\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\":\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\"item3\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\"}\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\"}\\\\\\\\\\\\\\",\\\\\\\\\\\\\\"{\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\"questionItem\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\":\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\"{\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\"id\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\":4,\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\"value\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\":\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\"item4\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\"}\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\"}\\\\\\\\\\\\\\"]\\\\\\"}\\",\\"value\\":\\"value\\",\\"minItems\\":2,\\"maxItems\\":5,\\"media\\":\\"media\\"}"}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

O problema está na linha:

```
object.put("questionItem",values.toString());
```

Você está mandando a biblioteca converter os valores para uma String (que contém aspas`"`) e colocá-los na propriedade `questionItem`. O json está escapando aspas com o caracter `\`.

Veja que o Java EE 7 já possui uma implementação de [JsonObject](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/json/JsonObject.html), bem como um meio simples de criar objetos aninhados. Se você precisa de uma API Standalone, basta incorporar [a RI](https://jsonp.java.net/) no seu projeto.

```
JsonObject model = Json.createObjectBuilder()
   .add("user", Json.createObjectBuilder()
      .add("id", user.getId())
      .add("username", user.getPassword())
      .add("password", user.getPassword())
   .add("questionItem", Json.createObjectBuilder()
         .add("id", question.getId())
         .add("value", question.getItem())
   .build();
```

Comment: replace("\\","") é uma boa ?, porque alguns possuem mais caracteres \ ?

Comment: Não, você tem que aninhar os objetos corretamente ao invés de tentar adicionar strings de objetos dentro de outros objetos (veja meu exemplo utilizando a [RI da JSR 353](https://jsonp.java.net/)).

Comment: E alguns beans são convertidos para json com uma quantidade absurda de `\ ` pois o parser está sofrendo tentando encodar e desencodar essas Strings. Quanto mais vezes você tentar fazer isso, mais `\ ` terá no valor final.